# ¿Por qué usar obj == null en lugar de obj.equals(null) en Java?

Tags: java

Entiendo que la segunda opción va a ocasionar una excepción cuando en realidad sea nulo ¿Pero existe alguna otra razón?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`equals`, se supone que compara que el contenido de dos objetos sea equivalente, más allá de su identidad (o sea la instancia del objeto, que se compara con `==`).

Una variable no es un objeto, es el contenedor de un tipo de dato/objeto. Si la variable vale `null` no puedes compararlo como igualdad pues no hay ningún objeto que comparar.

Answer (score 5):

EL operador `==` compara la referencia del objeto. y el `.equals()` comprueba si dos objetos son iguales, pero, aunque los objetos son iguales **null** al compararse se obtendra un `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 2):

La razón es porqué se desea comparar la referencia y para este fin es mejor utilizar el operador `==`

El método [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) comparará la igualdad de  `valor` de dos objetos. el parámetro enviado debe ser un `Objeto` y no una referencia si no se presentará [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

A Partir de Java `7.0` se añadio un Método [equals(Object a ,Object b)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) de la clase [Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html)  para comprobar esto

```
Objects.equals(null,valor)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mi opinión:

Cuando comparas dos objetos con (==) lo que estas comparando es si las dos referencias apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria donde esta ubicado el objeto.

Ejemplo:

Persona persona1 = new Persona();
Persona persona2 = new Persona();

si comparas.

persona1 == persona2  -> el resultado será falso.

pero si haces esto:

persona2 = persona1 -> estas indicando que persona2 referencie al objeto referenciado por persona1.

entonces al comparar.

persona1 == persona2 -> dará true.

Caso 2 equals.

El método equals está declarado en la clase principal Object, indica si dos objetos son iguales(si tienen el mismo contenido), todas las clases en java heredan de object explícita o implicitamente.

En el caso de la clase java.lang.String si verificamos la documentación sobreescribe el método equals.

Ejemplo:

String nombre1 = "joel";
String nombre2 = "joel";

nombre1.equals(nombre2)  -> El resultado será verdadero ya que tienen el mismo contenido.

Si tu quisieras comparar tus propios objetos creados, mediante equals, lo que tienes que hacer es sobreescribir el método equals y implementarlo.

En la documentación de Java se dice como se tiene que implementar el método equals siguiendo su contrato.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

El operador == realiza la comparación a nivel de objeto. Es decir, determina si ambos objetos son iguales.

El método equals() compara los caracteres dentro del objeto String.

Comment: Estas bastante equivocado. Deberías borrar esta respuesta para no confundir a la gente. Ninguna de las dos cosas que has puesto es cierta. Lo cierto es lo que pone @rnd